# Syntax Highlighting no textview Android

Tags: android, sintaxe

Vocês conhecem alguma biblioteca ou método para apresentar código fonte (Syntax Highlighting) no textview?

Preciso fazer isso para centenas de códigos (média de uns 400), apenas para leitura.

Algo semelhante a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: Precisa ser editável? Ou só `read-only` mesmo?

Comment: Só para leitura mesmo!

Comment: Matheus, dê uma olhada nessa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19787125/3404639, ela usa o `Java Pretiffy` com uma pequena adaptação. Acho que deve ajudar a começar a implementar.

Answer (score 1):

1: Existe um projeto open-source chamado Shader Editor:

https://github.com/markusfisch/ShaderEditor/blob/master/src/de/markusfisch/android/shadereditor/ShaderEditor.java

2: Você poderá usar HTML + JavaScript:
Existem várias ferramentas de colorir sintaxe em JavaScript. Veja [este](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). É usado neste [blog](http://www.technicalypto.com/search/label/TRIE).

Fontes:

1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285135/194717

2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7339016/194717